# null object reference on fragment new instance

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to run an instance of fragment from activity. But it returns error null object reference.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mani.view.StaggeredGridView.addItem(com.mani.view.StaggeredGridViewItem)' on a null object reference
 at com.example.myapp.FavouriteListFragment.onCreateView(FavouriteListFragment.java:57)
```

When i debug, this line shows null pointer error

```
  mStaggeredView.addItem(item);
```

debug result shows that fragmentClass is null value. It does not works well now after I have added inheritance class in my fragment. Here is my fragment

```
    public class FavouriteListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "favorite_list";
    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    private StaggeredGridView mStaggeredView;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
    String text;
    String favouriteUrl;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite_staggeredgridview, container, false);
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

        iv=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        text = sharedPreference.getValue(getActivity());

        sharedPreference.saveFavourite(getActivity(), text);

        String[] photoUrl;
        photoUrl = new String[10];

        for (int index = 0; index < photoUrl.length; index++) {

            photoUrl[index]=text;
            StaggeredGridViewItem item = null;
            item = new FavouriteGridItem(getActivity(),photoUrl); //pass one image of index
            mStaggeredView.addItem(item);
        }

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(text);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the portion of code in which you instantiate this ``fragmentClass``?

Comment: Verify that you are assigning a value to the variable `fragmentClass`.

Comment: why are u calling with a variable if its static. Check whether variable is null or not. Debug first,its the first step of solving any problem

Comment: what is a fragmentClass ?

Comment: hi all, it works fine now once i have removed this line fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();. but i m having another error, null pointer at item = new FavouriteGridItem(getActivity(),photoUrl);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is one of your problems:

```
mStaggeredView.addItem(item);
```

From the code you posted it is logical that you get a nullpointer on `mStaggeredView.addItem()` because you did not assign anything to `mStaggeredView`. You must do something like `mStaggeredGridView = (StaggeredGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.some_id)` somewhere

Comment: @0xDEADCODE ,I just realise that i didnt assign findviewbyid for the staggeredgridview.it is working fine now, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Are you also able to solve your other problem with `FavouriteGridItem`?

Comment: Yes, currently I am able to display images now :)

Comment: Are you sure about this ? The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) puts `onAttach()` before `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @DanChaltiel You're correct. I updated the answer. Unfortunately it's too long ago that I wrote this, so I have no clue why I said that :|